# Changing company name and email address in Enterprise and Apple store developer account

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

My company wants to change the the Developer name  in the Developer Account at the App Store& enterprise store . In this case, what would happen to the existing apps:

1. Will the existing apps remain happily at the App Store & enterprise store without any effect?
2. Will I need to get new certificates from the Developer portal(AppStore& enterprise) ?
3. If yes, will I need to submit a new build of my Apps in both cases ?
4. Will my enterprise apps will stop working (if my existing profiles and certificates needs to be recreated)

Please help me with this.